# Ассемблер. Ассемблерные вставки. Строки

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Как копировать одну строку в другую. Например, строка `text1[6]="fsdfaf"` копируется в `text2[6]={0}`

Comment: например в цикле, побайтно. Или rep movsb (scasb я видел вы делали, так что видимо знаете как такие инструкции работают)

Comment: спасибо, а как можно сделать, чтобы в новую строку скопировалось несколько пробелов а после этих пробелов шла строка

Comment: Если уж идти по аналогии, то rep stosb кладете пробелы, и после начинаете копировать строку (в целевом буфере места должно хватать, о размерах заботьтесь заранее). А вообще если уж изучаете ассемблер забудьте пока про эти специализированные команды и делайте все обычными циклами и mov, что бы лучше чувствовать что куда кладете.